# Not able to get jcr:content of rootVersion node

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I have created a node and created 2 versions of it using VersionManager checkout and checkin feature.
I am adding/setting xyz files contents in jcr:content property.

```
version::jcr:rootVersion
hasNode:jcr_content :false
version::1.0
hasNode:jcr_content :true
version::1.1
hasNode:jcr_content :true
```

But when I am trying to get all versions data using below code, I am not able to get jcr:content property of jcr:rootVersion node. I am able to to fetch files contents using jcr:content property of version 1.0 and 1.1

```
if (node.isNodeType(NodeType.MIX_VERSIONABLE)) {
    final VersionHistory versionHistory = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager().getVersionHistory(node.getPath());
    final VersionIterator itr = versionHistory.getAllVersions();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        final Version v = itr.nextVersion();
        final Node frozenNode = v.getFrozenNode();
        log.info("version::" + v.getName());
        log.info("hasNode:jcr_content :" + frozenNode.hasNode(Property.JCR_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

How I can get files content from rootversion node, why jcr:content property is not available for root version in jcr version history.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html#3.13.5.2%20Root%20Version:

> 3.13.5.2 Root Version
>
> Each version history has a root version, which is a null version that
> stores no state; it simply serves as the eventual predecessor of all
> subsequent versions.
>
> The root version is accessed through VersionHistory.getRootVersion
> (see 15.1.1.1 Root Version). Under full versioning it is also
> represented as an nt:version child node of the nt:versionHistory node,
> called jcr:rootVersion.

Comment: I have tried to get it by VersionHistory.getRootVersion(), but no luck. As it is a null version that stores no state, it means we can not get its jcr content, right?

Comment: According to my project requirement, I wanted to get file jcr contents of root version node.

Comment: The requirement doesn't make any ssnse given how JCR is defined.

Comment: Actually, we have requirement to compare file contents of root version and version 1.0, so it is not fulfilling our need.

Comment: Well, you can either tell the person making up these requirement that these are nonsensical, or give up and assume for the purpose of comparison that the root versions has *empty* contents. Or, alternatively, hide the root version entirely so nobody asks.

Comment: Before losing root version file contents, we can make its 1.0 version and fulfill our need.